# On Mautic I cannot find the input box to enter the AWS SES hostname on Mautic version 3.0 I can see it on Mautic version 2.16 just fine

Tags: mautic

I have recently installed a new Mautic ver 3.0 previous version was 2.16 and all was fine with that version.
When following the directions i tried to insert the host name for the AWS SES hostname there was no input box. I have viewed several youtube and each one shows the insertion box.. however they were all version 2.16... I asked this question a week ago on Mautic and no answer... and now I see that all the smart Mautic folks are here on stackoverflow. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you did not get an answer yet - was that on the forums?

Since 3.2 (please make sure that you are on the latest version as we [recently issued critical security fixes](https://www.mautic.org/blog/community/security-release-all-versions-mautic-prior-2-16-5-and-3-2-4)) Amazon SES should be configured with the API option. This is highly recommended owing to it being much more efficient.

That being said, you will need to select the region from the dropdown on both STMP:

[image: Screenshot of SMTP Amazon SES settings]

and on API:

[image: Screenshot of API Amazon SES settings]

Comment: It's not working yet for me fully yet, but your comments have moved me forward... 
Your image shows two different points for inputting the SES user and pass... the two red boxes.. I only see one input box on my email page... I still need to get my api key when ready to go into the Api. I have my domains and emails all verified and can send from one email to the other via the email test send.. but when I click the Test for the Amazon Test it gives  long error.. I can send the error if it might help you analyze.
Clicking test on the bounce and unsubscribe all work fine..

Comment: Are you on 3.2.5? Or 3.0? If the latter, that is the problem. Lots of fixes and features have come out since 3.0, which is also vulnerable to attack (see the blog on mautic.org for info).

Comment: Thanks Ruth.... but I recently loaded up the very latest version and still no work. I am giving up on this just too hard... but thanks a million for the help.